# Unloading CEF crashes

Tags: c++, chromium-embedded

We want to show some browser windows from inside an MFC dll (Visual Studio 2015). Unfortunately, as soon as we unload CEF, it crashes. We found very similar questions but never an answer.

To have a better look at the problem, we moved all CEF stuff inside another dll (cefwrapper). These are the main steps we basically do:

```
1.  LoadLibrary(cefwrapper.dll) 
2.  Inside cefwrapper.dll
    a.  CefString(&settings.browser_subprocess_path) = "cefsimple.exe"
    b.  CefInitialize(args, settings, this, NULL)
    c.  window_info.SetAsChild(hwnd, rect);
    d.  browser_ = CefBrowserHost::CreateBrowserSync(window_info, browser_client_.get(), url, browser_settings, request_context);
    e.  ::SetParent(browser_->GetHost()->GetWindowHandle(), NULL); // Prevent getting a CLOSE Message
    f.  CloseBrowser();
    g.  Waiting until OnBeforeClose was called for all browsers.
    h.  CefShutdown();
    i.  (all sub-processes (cefsimple.exe) are gone by now)
3.  FreeLibrary --> Crash
```

CallStack

```
libcef.dll!sandbox::BrokerServicesBase::~BrokerServicesBase() Line 135  C++
libcef.dll!sandbox::SingletonBase<sandbox::BrokerServicesBase>::OnExit() Line 63    C++
libcef.dll!_execute_onexit_table::__l2::<lambda>() Line 206 C++
libcef.dll!__crt_seh_guarded_call<int>::operator()<<lambda_7777bce6b2f8c936911f934f8298dc43>,int <lambda>(void) & __ptr64,<lambda_3883c3dff614d5e0c5f61bb1ac94921c> >(__acrt_lock_and_call::__l2::<lambda_7777bce6b2f8c936911f934f8298dc43> && setup, _execute_onexit_table::__l2::int <lambda>(void) & action, __acrt_lock_and_call::__l2::<lambda_3883c3dff614d5e0c5f61bb1ac94921c> && cleanup) Line 204  C++
libcef.dll!_execute_onexit_table(_onexit_table_t * table) Line 231  C++
libcef.dll!common_exit::__l2::<lambda>() Line 230   C++
libcef.dll!__crt_seh_guarded_call<void>::operator()<<lambda_d80eeec6fff315bfe5c115232f3240e3>,void <lambda>(void) & __ptr64,<lambda_2358e3775559c9db80273638284d5e45> >(__acrt_lock_and_call::__l2::<lambda_d80eeec6fff315bfe5c115232f3240e3> && setup, common_exit::__l2::void <lambda>(void) & action, __acrt_lock_and_call::__l2::<lambda_2358e3775559c9db80273638284d5e45> && cleanup) Line 224 C++
libcef.dll!common_exit(const int return_code, const _crt_exit_cleanup_mode cleanup_mode, const _crt_exit_return_mode return_mode) Line 278  C++
```

Not calling FreeLibrary will postpone the problem to the point where the application exits.

We are using cef_binary_73.1.12+gee4b49f+chromium-73.0.3683.75_windows64

As an alternative, we started cefsimple.exe via CreateProcess and passed the hwnd to that process. Unfortunately, after some time, the browser window freezes.

Comment: Are you sure that at the point of unloading / exiting there are no alive cef objects and there are no references to static data or functions from cef?

Comment: There are still some threads running after calling Shutdown(). E.g. BrokerEvent libcef.dll!sandbox::BrokerServicesBase::TargetEventsThread, TaskSchedulerServiceThread libcef.dll!base::`anonymous namespace'::WaitUntil, CacheThread_BlockFile libcef.dll!base::MessagePumpForIO::WaitForIOCompletion, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Never call `FreeLibrary` for CEF DLL.

Chromium has many global objects (singletons, utility threads) that are supposed to be alive till the application end. It's done for faster application termination: global objects and singletons are not deleted, threads are not terminated, nobody worries about it at process termination.

When you call `FreeLibrary`, you corrupt this architecture. Threads started from CEF leave alive, but DLL memory is freed. Thus you get crash.

To fix it just do not perform the step 3.

Comment: Thanks for your input. That destroys my hopes of finding a solution. We initialize CEF inside a dll. This dll can be loaded and unloaded at runtime by our customers. As soon as the dll gets unloaded, cef crashes whether we perform step 3 or not.

Comment: It does not matter where CefInititialize called from. It seems some references to CEF objects from your application are still existing after CefShutdown.